# Reading second mail using python

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I want to read an outlook file (.msg file) which is a reply to a mail. I am able to read the details of the reply.
But I want to read the original mail to which the reply is sent. I want to read the date it was sent (the original mail).

The mail is present in the form of .msg file. I am using win32com to read the file but can only read the reply not the main mail.
The main mail is present below the reply in that file but how to read that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to read the date header from the reply in the message body?

Comment: My point is: A sent mail to B and B replied to A. I have the message file/outlook html file of that reply which B sent. So using win32com the details I can fetch are of the reply only, but I need the details of the mail which A sent to B. Only the date on which it was sent on. And fyi it is a .msg file which is present in a folder in system.

Comment: Where in the file is it? In the message body? Can you see it in OutlookSpy (click OpenIMshOnIStg to open the MSG file).